# Using mock data in eclipse which doesn't produce warnings

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface, mocking

How can I create a layout file with data and fill them with some example data so that I can see what I have done without producing warnings.

Here is an example:

[image: Simple android UI]

If I remove the text (which wants Android Lint) I have a plain blue screen, which is not helpful at all.

By the way this is the warning:

> [I18N] Hardcoded string "Foobar", should use @string resource example.xml /Example/res/layout Line 42 Android Lint Problem

Comment: you could use some `@string` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an entry in your strings.xml for each of your example Strings.

On the other hand, this is a Lint warning. You can safely ignore this without causing immediate harm to your app, as these are only meant to guide you in best practices.

[image]

Go to the Eclipse preferences, into the `Android` submenu, then into the `Lint Error Checking` menu and disable the `HardcodedText` warning.

**Second Method**

Instead of setting the example text through XML, use the setText() through Java code, and enclose it in an if condition as follows:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    view.setText("My example text");
}
```

BuildConfig.DEBUG was added in ADT 17, and is true whenever you do a debug build. When you export the apk, it is set to false. As the variable is set to false and never reassigned, the Java compiler will optimize your code and remove these statements. They will not be compiled into a production app.

Comment: I don't want risk to leave garbage in the final app.

Comment: In that case, you can disable the warning for now. Let me edit my post.

Comment: In that case the example strings will be compiled into the app, I want to avoid that too.

Comment: If you want to make sure that the example Strings aren' compiled into the app for production, there's another thing you can do. Let me edit my post again.

Comment: Your last edit is almost perfect. But this does not effect the visual editor in eclipse.

Comment: @rekire You can't see Java changes in the visual editor sadly. For that, you'll have to either use Strings.xml or set the text in the XML as you are doing right now.

Comment: I'll wait some time maybe somebody else has an idea. +1 for your effort.

Comment: @rekire regarding "I don't want risk to leave garbage in the final app" Why? Having a few mock string resources (e.g. just 2 - 1 for shorter titles, 1 for longer texts) defined in your app that are in fact unused during runtime does not impact your app in any perceivable way. The tools currently don't support previewing layouts with mock text and even the text you hardcode in your layout xml is going to be part of the app if you leave it there. So the difference between `@string` and hardcoded strings is roughly 0 anyways.